# roscd cannot find the package

Tags: ros, roscd, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everytime I compile a package I'm working on, or try to use a new package, ROS cannot find the package. I've even restarted from scratch. For example, this afternoon I'm trying to run [a publisher for an imu](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_3dm_gx4). So I started from scratch because nothing is working, again. After 30 minuts of looking for a mistake, googling, etc. it just starts to work. This is what I'm doing:

```
myuser@mypc:$ cd ros
myuser@mypc:$ rm -rf *
myuser@mypc:$ mkdir src
myuser@mypc:$ cd src
myuser@mypc:$ catkin_init_workspace
myuser@mypc:$ cp -r ~/develeopment/imu .
myuser@mypc:$ cd ..
myuser@mypc:$ catkin_make

Base path: /home/myuser/development/ros
Source space: /home/myuser/development/ros/src
Build space: /home/myuser/development/ros/build
Devel space: /home/myuser/development/ros/devel
Install space: /home/myuser/development/ros/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/myuser/development/ros/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/myuser/development/ros/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/myuser/development/ros/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/myuser/development/ros/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/myuser/development/ros/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/myuser/development/ros/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/myuser/development/ros/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/myuser/development/ros/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - imu_3dm_gx4
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'imu_3dm_gx4'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(imu_3dm_gx4)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- imu_3dm_gx4: 1 messages, 0 services
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/myuser/development/ros/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/myuser/development/ros/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target _imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_check_deps_FilterOutput
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target _imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_check_deps_FilterOutput
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] [ 50%] [ 50%] Generating Lisp code from imu_3dm_gx4/FilterOutput.msg
Generating C++ code from imu_3dm_gx4/FilterOutput.msg
Generating Python from MSG imu_3dm_gx4/FilterOutput
[ 50%] Built target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_lisp
[ 66%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for imu_3dm_gx4
[ 66%] Built target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_py
[ 66%] Built target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target imu_3dm_gx4
Scanning dependencies of target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages
[ 66%] Built target imu_3dm_gx4_generate_messages
[100%] [100%] Building CXX object imu_3dm_gx4/CMakeFiles/imu_3dm_gx4.dir/src/imu_3dm_gx4.cpp.o
Building CXX object imu_3dm_gx4/CMakeFiles/imu_3dm_gx4.dir/src/imu.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/myuser/development/ros/devel/lib/imu_3dm_gx4/imu_3dm_gx4
[100%] Built target imu_3dm_gx4
```

So the package is found, compiled and linked. Then I do:

```
 myuser@mypc:$ source devel/setup.bash
 myuser@mypc:$ roscd imu_3dm_gx4
 roscd: No such package/stack 'imu_3dm_gx4'
```

Now I keep trying to make it work, searching on the web, running it again, until it suddenly works. This has happened all time the past week, and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong or what system variable I've missconfigured.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04, ros indigo.

Any light on this matter would be greatly appreciated. As crazy as it may sound, it looks as the changes take time to appear.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217974/roscd-cannot-find-the-package/) by [jcolmena](https://answers.ros.org/users/23974/jcolmena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-09-25**:
I see you edited your terminal log to use `catkin_init_workspace`. Did my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I assume your fifth line should read `catkin_init_workspace` instead of `catkin_make`. I believe your issue is likely related to the cache used by `rospack`. Quoting from the [rospack docs](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/rospack.html#efficiency-considerations):

> rospack re-parses the manifest.xml files and rebuilds the dependency tree on each execution. However, it maintains a cache of package directories in ROS_ROOT/.rospack_cache. This cache is updated whenever there is a cache miss, or when the cache is 60 seconds old. You can change this timeout by setting the environment variable ROS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, in seconds. Set it to 0.0 to force a cache rebuild on every invocation of rospack.

I have encountered exactly the same sort of behaviour that you are reporting in the past, and I've always understood this behavior to simply mean that the `rospack` cache is out of date. Running the command `rospack profile` will force `rospack` to re-crawl your active workspaces and refresh the cache. [This page](http://wiki.ros.org/rospack/Troubleshooting) also supports my theory. Hope this info helps.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3